# How do I load a text dataset batch by batch/ multiple lines at a time using Python+Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset, deep-learning, word-embedding

So, I'm trying to get started on text classification and the likes in Tensorflow and Python.

The initial step in attempting such tasks is to build embeddings. Consequently, I'd started working with the GloVe pretrained vector 840B 300d set(around 5 GB).

I ran into problems right away when trying to load the dataset itself. I run a CPU based Tensor-Flow version (No NVidia/ advantage of GPUs :( )

It gets stuck for an insanely long time and there seems to be no workaround this. I tried passing the input in stages like the following.

File has been initialized already as file=('glove.840B.300d.txt','r') and works. Now...

```
def scanlin(n):
    for i in range(n,n+20):
        line=file.readline(i)
        if line=='':
            break
        splitline=line.split()
        word=splitline[0]
        embedding=[float(val) for val in splitline[1:]]
        model[word]=embedding
    print('Done')
```

It executes succesfully but when I call the function as scanlin(1), it says

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   File "", line 8, in scanlin File "", line 8, in
>    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

I then tried making the 'embedding' as 'embedding.append()' but same error.

However, when I do it to a limited extent, it works upto n=50000 words with some effort.

```
def loadset(file):
    i=1
    for line in file:
        if(i>n):
            break
        values=line.strip().split(" ")
        word=values[0]
        coefs= [float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]]
        embeddings_index[word]=coefs
        i=i+1
    return coefs,embeddings_index
```

The above works and I can load the embeddings for each word, but how do I change it to sequentially process the input data on each call and integrate it into the load dataset fully? This is Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Tensorflow and I need to work with much huger datasets soon.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to avoid loading the whole dataset into memory, and instead have TensorFlow iterate over it? If so, you'll want to [use TensorFlow ops for reading](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#reading_from_files).

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped :D